# python requests, with same headers of chrome browser, get 403 errors

Tags: python, python-requests

I have written some code for scraping 
 
that program uses `requests.get(url, headers=headers)` 
with headers exactly same with my Chrome browser except cookie

Initially, It works fine. but later. It gets 403 error 
My Chrome browser get that data very well without error 
but My python requests code doesn't work. What is the problem. I don't know

```
url = 'http://www.matchesfashion.com/en-kr/products/1171735'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Whale/0.10.36.11 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'ko-KR,ko;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
    'Host': 'www.matchesfashion.com',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Comment: When you get `403`, do all following requests fail with the same status code? A quick test with `50` requests gave me `200` for all of them.

Comment: It works for a while, but after about 3-4hrs, It dose not work.

Comment: I am wondering why my script that has same headers with my Chrome browser get detected as robot

Comment: How many / how often are you making requests? There is probably some kind of rate limiting going on.

Comment: about every 10 seconds .. If rate limit banned me, why my chrome browser works well? I don't know